# trigonometric angle tangent identity, a and b are equivalent?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question about trigonometric angle identities.

if $\tan(a)=\cot(b)$

can I say $a=b$?

$a$ and $b$ are in rads respectively. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No $a$ and $b$ are not equal.$a=n\pi+b$ where $n$ is an positive integer.

Comment: sorry my question was messed up, i've fixed it now

Comment: $\tan{\frac{\pi}{6}}=\cot{\frac{\pi}{3}}$

Comment: The reverse is not true either.

Answer (score 2):

Then: $\dfrac{sina}{cosa} = \dfrac{cosb}{sinb} \to cosa\cdot cosb - sina\cdot sinb = 0 \to cos(a+b) = 0 \to a+b = (2n+1)\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\tan a=\cot b\Rightarrow \cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b=0\iff \cos(a+b)=0$$
so we find that
$$a+b\equiv\frac\pi2\mod\pi$$
with the conditions
$$a\not\equiv0\mod\pi\quad\text{and}\quad b\not\equiv\frac\pi2\mod\pi$$

Comment: what does mod min? thanks

Comment: $x\equiv y\mod z$ means $x-y$ is a multiple of $z$.

Comment: Well done, as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. For example, $\tan \pi/6 = \cot\pi/6$, as the commenters pointed out.

There are very few angles for which $\tan x = \cot x$ holds, as for it to hold, the equality $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$
would have to be true. That is only true if $$\sin^2 x =\cos^2 x$$ or $$\sin^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x,$$ meaning $\sin x = \pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.

Answer (score -1):

No probably not as -
$$tan (a) = cot (b)$$
$$\implies tan (a) = 1/tan(b)$$
$$\implies tan (a) tan(b)=1 $$
$$\implies 1-tan(a)tan(b)=0 ...\alpha$$ 
Now 
$$\begin{align}
\tan(a+b)&=\frac{tan(a)+tan(b)}{1-tan(a) tan(b)}\\\end{align}$$
But from $\alpha$ we have
$$1-tan(a)tan(b)=0$$
$$\implies tan(a+b)=\infty$$
$$\implies a+b=arctan\infty$$
$$\implies a+b=90$$
$$\implies a=90-b$$
So if $$tan(a)=cot(b)$$,then $$a=90-b$$

Comment: $tan(a+b)$ will be $\infty$

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria thanks for correcting my silly mistake!

Comment: still you re going wrong. scrutinize.

Comment: what is the mistake plz explain.And what does scrutinize mean?

Comment: first thing a & b are in rads. second thing tan function is infinite at $(n\pi)/2$ where $n$ is any odd integer